# Hashing algorithms for Internal application

Tags: security, model-view-controller, sha, owasp

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question as there is no right and wrong answer.

I have a MVC5 application with WCF service and it will be used internally. However it requires some security as it involves finance stuffs and cannot ignore even though it is internal.

So how can I ensure that the application is secure??
Do I need to use hashing algorithms > SHA1

Comment: Do you mean for passwords? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846

Comment: The question is a little too broad, try asking more specifically. Of course you need to hash passwords, but hashing is obviously not the appropriate way to protect data that has to be read/modified in the future. Oh, and you should use *at least* SHA2 instead of SHA1.

Comment: @Numbers Yes, it is broad. Ok, to make it simpler, let's say you have a MVC5 application and a WCF service and there is no security in place. How do you secure it?

Comment: @Gray Can be anything. It has not implemented any security

Comment: There is a specific closing flag for this type of question: too broad. Stack Overflow simply isn't the right place for asking such a question. Either you're willing to give some additional details about your application, or you probably won't get anything but downvotes. Nothing personal, in fact I think security questions like this are very interesting, but they *need to* be specific if asked here.

Comment: One more suggestion, because I really think the question could be good: if you are concerned about a lot of key points (e.g. passwords, network communication, privacy), specifying all of them makes the question interesting and worth an answer, even if broad. Asking "Hey guys how do I implement security in [*language/framework of choice*]" is not going to be very useful, in my humble opinion of course.

Comment: @taccacc The problem is that there is a fundamental difference in password storage versus other confidential data. Not to sound rude, but it should not be you who is implementing this. You could unwittingly put your company at risk for losing a lot of money. You specifically mention financial data, and there are laws (in the US) regarding how this data is stored. I'm sure you are a good developer, you just aren't a security expert. This is one of those times where you approach your manager and admit you need help - training/consultants/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hash algorithm like SHA1 does not secure your application. 
It just respond to one good practice "hash your password on your database with a good algorithm". 
If you want a secure application, I recommend you to read OWASP Application Verification Standard (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project) and implement all the level4 requirements